# How to compile GDAL with external libraries? (Rasterlite2)

Tags: gdal, compile

I want to compile GDAL with Rasterlite2 Support, but I can't find any info on how to do this.

I already downloaded librasterlite2, libspatialite and libsqlite3.

When configuring with `--with-rasterlite2=path`, I only get an error:

```
checking for rl2_load_raw_tiles_into_dbms in -lrasterlite2... no
configure: error: did not find rl2_load_raw_tiles_into_dbms
```

Is the downloaded source from https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/index wrong?

I'm on Windows and want to compile with mSys/MinGW

Comment: I found this https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/vinfo?name=7fcdba3cdf826c53 version of librasterlite2 which has the rl2_load_raw_tiles_into_dbms, but the error remains :/